# Creating a copy of an object in Python without using deepcopy

Tags: python, class, memory, garbage-collection, copy

I have been taking a look at improving the runtime of a Python class' copy operation which currently utilizes the copy.deepcopy() function:

```
def Foo(object):

    ...

    copy_method(self):
         return copy.deepcopy(self)
```

This class does not inherit from any other classes. Consequently, I was considering an alternative to the above that is far more efficient from a runtime perspective, but makes me question if any memory issues will occur as there is no Factory or ObjectManger for the class "Foo" mentioned above:

```
    @classmethod
    new_instance(cls):
        return cls.__new__(cls)

    copy_method(self):
        new = self.new_instance()
        new.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)
        return new
```

Is this implementation a terrible idea? I understand the utility of deepcopy() in regard to classes with complex structure, etc, but this proposed method is far more efficient given the Foo class' simple structure. Or is this a horrible mistake that would lead to issues with garbage collection and memory management? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice for a first question :)

Comment: Thank you very much Chris :)